# U-SQL equivalent of HASHBYTES to get hash of complete row

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

We have to store all the changes in a data row. I was looking for in build function like SQL Server to calculate HASHBYTES and time-stamp to find the changes and get the latest one as well.
Any pointer will be highly helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to SHA2 hash a string in USQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590920/how-to-sha2-hash-a-string-in-usql)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply (I must have missed this question during my trip).

Would something like the answer to this question help you?

[How to SHA2 hash a string in USQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590920/how-to-sha2-hash-a-string-in-usql)